# add new frames to an existing gif without changing its url

Tags: url, addition, gif

im trying to add mutaple frames at a time to a gif without changing its url location. here's is an example of a gif id be adding new frames to.

https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI0ez6cIRCSr3kk/giphy.gif

right now i had to go through a very time consuming process to add new frames and i have to change the url location to top it off so if theirs a web page that allows me to do this youd be helping me out a tun. the faster the process the better because ill be doing it alot

Answer (score 0):

You can add suffix after "?" to url for reloading it with out web cache.
for example:

```
http://server/.../name.gif?anysymbols
```

but you need web hosting for storing your files.

Upload via ftp to server and then check it in your browser.